# How to know if a variable of NSString* type is null?

Tags: ios, nsstring

When I debug a ios app, a variable of NSString* type returned by a function shows 0x00000000 in print command, but how would I write codes to know it?

Comment: if you satisfied my answer so please upvote my answer.thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ([str isEqual:[NSNull null]])
   {

   }
```

Hope this code is useful for you.